# How do I make divs that close and hide on click close from within the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, show-hide

Basically, I have code where the user clicks a link, and then a div appears. The user than has to click the same link to make this div disappear. I have eight divs. How do I set it up so that you can click another link within the div to close it, rather than clicking the same link you used to open it? My code is below.

http://www.lovehatecreate.net/iqhomes/jquery-show-hide-plugin-2/index.php

Please ignore the lines that say syntax error. The code still works, I just forgot to upload a file for something not relevant to my question that is on the page.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.  You may also want to create a fiddle, as those are easier for people to analyze the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vwnUv/) cover your use case?

Excerpt:

```
$('.show').click(function () {
    var divId = $(this).data('divId');
    $('#' + divId).toggle();
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the `<div>`s a class indicating they're to be grouped together (only one open at a time), then on link click, hide every element with that class **before** showing the one for the link you clicked.
If you want to combine this with toggle, get the toggle state before hiding them all, so you know to leave it closed if it was open.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete bins on codebins, please check demo link once.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7c

**HTML**

```
<div id="links">
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
  <a class="openlink" href="javascript:void(0);">
    Open
  </a>
</div>
<div id="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Here is Content..!! 
    </p>
    <p>
      <a class="closelink" href="javascript:void(0);">
        Close
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var boxClone;

    $(".openlink").click(function() {
        //Clone Dialogbox
        boxClone = $("#boxes").find(".box:eq(0)").clone(true, true);
        var boxOffset = $("#boxes").find(".box:last").position();
        //Set Dialog Position
        if (boxOffset.top == 0) {
            boxOffset.top = 5;
        }
        if (boxOffset.left == 0) {
            boxOffset.left = 60;
        }
        $(boxClone).css('top', (boxOffset.top + 20));
        $(boxClone).css('left', (boxOffset.left + 20));
        $(boxClone).appendTo($("#boxes"));
        $(boxClone).show(500);
    });

    //Close Dialogbox
    $(".closelink").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".box").remove();
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#links{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid #92a3a7;
  padding:1px;
  background:#88ddfa;
}
#links a{
  dispslay:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#3543ff;
}
#links a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:#fd2211;
}
#boxes{
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
#boxes p{
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  color:#ccc;
}
#boxes a.closelink{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ff2211;
  background:#99cd9a;
  width:40px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:3px;
  font-size:14px;
}
#boxes a.closelink:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  background:#a5d9a3;
  color:#2222ff;
}

.box{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:10px solid #888;
  background:url('http://www.lovehatecreate.net/iqhomes/jquery-show-hide-plugin-2/popupbg.png') #333;
  display:none;

}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7c